# how to convert date in dd/mm/yyyy to days in python csv

Tags: python, date, data-cleaning, days

i will like to covert dates to days

Example 01/01/2001 should be Day 1, 02/01/2001 should be Day 2

I have tried

prices_df['01/01/2001'] = prices_df['days'].dt.days

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using any external function or a complicated solution, you can simply take the first 2 chars of the string.

```
int('01/01/2001'[0:2])
```

Output:

```
1
```

If you have to do this in a pandas column:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_numeric(df['days'].str[0:2])
```

**N.B.** This works if all date are in the form day/month/year

Comment: Hi Will,  I have tried this but this did not woork for me. i need a fuction to count the total number of days in the 'days' column between a start date of 1st Jan 1995 and an end date of 31st Dec 2019 in a dataframe taking leapyears into account as well.                                            
  Example: Ist Jan 1995 - Day 1, 1st Feb 1995 - Day 32 .......and so on all the way to 31st Dec 2019.

Comment: @Dera this is another question... I answered for your previous question. Vote my answer as correct. Then open a new question and send me the link to the new question.

Comment: Hi Will, it's my first day using stack overflow so i wasn't aware i needed to vote, now i know. Thanks

Comment: here is the link to the question:  
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74353426/how-to-convert-date-format-dd-mm-yyyy-to-days-in-python-csv