# How to convert date format (dd/mm/yyyy) to days in python csv

Tags: python, function, date

I need a function to count the total number of days in the 'days' column between a start date of 1st Jan 1995 and an end date of 31st Dec 2019 in a dataframe taking leap years into account as well.

Example: 1st Jan 1995 - Day 1, 1st Feb 1995 - Day 32 .......and so on all the way to 31st.

[image]

Comment: Is this a [tag:pandas] question? If so please add the `pandas` tag. Subtract from a `date` object that represents your reference date, get the number of days from the resulting `timedelta`s, add one? Did you [try anything](/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Did you do [any research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953)? [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](//stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/843953)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate number of days between two given dates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151199/how-to-calculate-number-of-days-between-two-given-dates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add column with number of days between dates in DataFrame pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22132525/add-column-with-number-of-days-between-dates-in-dataframe-pandas)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to filter a pandas dataframe using a range of 2 date you can do this by:

```
start_date = '1995/01/01'
end_date   = '1995/02/01'
df = df[ (df['days']>=start_date) & (df['days']<=end_date) ]
```

and with `len(df)` you will see the number of rows of the filter dataframe.

Instead, if you want to calculate a range of days between 2 different date you can do without pandas with datetime:

```
from datetime import datetime
start_date = '1995/01/01'
end_date   = '1995/02/01'
delta = datetime.strptime(end_date, '%Y/%m/%d') - datetime.strptime(start_date, '%Y/%m/%d')
print(delta.days)
```

Output:

```
31
```

The only thing is that this not taking into account leap years